# Bot Framework Greeting message with v4 Webchat Channel

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, chatbot, web-chat

I am trying to send a greeting message at the moment the web is loaded and the chatbot is initialized.
It works with the emulator but it doesn't seem to work that straight forward with  on the webchat channel.

I have researched and found a couple of useful links but I am missing something...

[[BotFramework]: How to fix:Welcome message is not getting displayed to the user in C# WebChatBot developed in V4 but displayed in Emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56111293/botframework-how-to-fixwelcome-message-is-not-getting-displayed-to-the-user)

[Display Welcome Message in v4 Bot Framework Bot (C# + .Net Core Web Application)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56863203/display-welcome-message-in-v4-bot-framework-bot-c-net-core-web-application)

https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/1397

So far this is my code:

**default.htm**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Core Bot Sample</title>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            font-family: Segoe UI;
        }

        html,
        body {
            height: 100%;
        }

        header {
            background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg version='1.1' id='Layer_1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' x='0px' y='0px' viewBox='0 0 4638.9 651.6' style='enable-background:new 0 0 4638.9 651.6;' xml:space='preserve'%3E%3Cstyle type='text/css'%3E .st0%7Bfill:%2355A0E0;%7D .st1%7Bfill:none;%7D .st2%7Bfill:%230058A8;%7D .st3%7Bfill:%23328BD8;%7D .st4%7Bfill:%23B6DCF1;%7D .st5%7Bopacity:0.2;fill:url(%23SVGID_1_);enable-background:new ;%7D%0A%3C/style%3E%3Crect y='1.1' class='st0' width='4640' height='646.3'/%3E%3Cpath class='st1' d='M3987.8,323.6L4310.3,1.1h-65.6l-460.1,460.1c-17.5,17.5-46.1,17.5-63.6,0L3260.9,1.1H0v646.3h3660.3 L3889,418.7c17.5-17.5,46.1-17.5,63.6,0l228.7,228.7h66.6l-260.2-260.2C3970.3,369.8,3970.3,341.1,3987.8,323.6z'/%3E%3Cpath class='st2' d='M3784.6,461.2L4244.7,1.1h-983.9l460.1,460.1C3738.4,478.7,3767.1,478.7,3784.6,461.2z'/%3E%3Cpath class='st3' d='M4640,1.1h-329.8l-322.5,322.5c-17.5,17.5-17.5,46.1,0,63.6l260.2,260.2H4640L4640,1.1L4640,1.1z'/%3E%3Cpath class='st4' d='M3889,418.8l-228.7,228.7h521.1l-228.7-228.7C3935.2,401.3,3906.5,401.3,3889,418.8z'/%3E%3ClinearGradient id='SVGID_1_' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse' x1='3713.7576' y1='438.1175' x2='3911.4084' y2='14.2535' gradientTransform='matrix(1 0 0 -1 0 641.3969)'%3E%3Cstop offset='0' style='stop-color:%23FFFFFF;stop-opacity:0.5'/%3E%3Cstop offset='1' style='stop-color:%23FFFFFF'/%3E%3C/linearGradient%3E%3Cpath class='st5' d='M3952.7,124.5c-17.5-17.5-46.1-17.5-63.6,0l-523,523h1109.6L3952.7,124.5z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E%0A");
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: 100%;
            background-position: right;
            background-color: #55A0E0;
            width: 100%;
            font-size: 44px;
            height: 120px;
            color: white;
            padding: 30px 0 40px 0px;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .header-icon {
            background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,%3Csvg%20version%3D%221.1%22%20id%3D%22Layer_1%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A//www.w3.org/2000/svg%22%20xmlns%3Axlink%3D%22http%3A//www.w3.org/1999/xlink%22%20x%3D%220px%22%20y%3D%220px%22%0A%09%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20150.2%20125%22%20style%3D%22enable-background%3Anew%200%200%20150.2%20125%3B%22%20xml%3Aspace%3D%22preserve%22%3E%0A%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text/css%22%3E%0A%09.st0%7Bfill%3Anone%3B%7D%0A%09.st1%7Bfill%3A%23FFFFFF%3B%7D%0A%3C/style%3E%0A%3Crect%20x%3D%220.5%22%20class%3D%22st0%22%20width%3D%22149.7%22%20height%3D%22125%22/%3E%0A%3Cg%3E%0A%09%3Cpath%20class%3D%22st1%22%20d%3D%22M59%2C102.9L21.8%2C66c-3.5-3.5-3.5-9.1%2C0-12.5l37-36.5l2.9%2C3l-37%2C36.4c-1.8%2C1.8-1.8%2C4.7%2C0%2C6.6l37.2%2C37L59%2C102.9z%22%0A%09%09/%3E%0A%3C/g%3E%0A%3Cg%3E%0A%09%3Cpath%20class%3D%22st1%22%20d%3D%22M92.5%2C102.9l-3-3l37.2-37c0.9-0.9%2C1.4-2%2C1.4-3.3c0-1.2-0.5-2.4-1.4-3.3L89.5%2C20l2.9-3l37.2%2C36.4%0A%09%09c1.7%2C1.7%2C2.6%2C3.9%2C2.6%2C6.3s-0.9%2C4.6-2.6%2C6.3L92.5%2C102.9z%22/%3E%0A%3C/g%3E%0A%3Cg%3E%0A%09%3Cpath%20class%3D%22st1%22%20d%3D%22M90.1%2C68.4c-4.5%2C0-8-3.5-8-8.1c0-4.5%2C3.5-8.1%2C8-8.1c4.4%2C0%2C8%2C3.7%2C8%2C8.1C98.1%2C64.7%2C94.4%2C68.4%2C90.1%2C68.4z%0A%09%09%20M90.1%2C56.5c-2.2%2C0-3.8%2C1.7-3.8%2C3.9c0%2C2.2%2C1.7%2C3.9%2C3.8%2C3.9c1.9%2C0%2C3.8-1.6%2C3.8-3.9S91.9%2C56.5%2C90.1%2C56.5z%22/%3E%0A%3C/g%3E%0A%3Cg%3E%0A%09%3Cpath%20class%3D%22st1%22%20d%3D%22M61.4%2C68.4c-4.5%2C0-8-3.5-8-8.1c0-4.5%2C3.5-8.1%2C8-8.1c4.4%2C0%2C8%2C3.7%2C8%2C8.1C69.5%2C64.7%2C65.8%2C68.4%2C61.4%2C68.4z%0A%09%09%20M61.4%2C56.5c-2.2%2C0-3.8%2C1.7-3.8%2C3.9c0%2C2.2%2C1.7%2C3.9%2C3.8%2C3.9c1.9%2C0%2C3.8-1.6%2C3.8-3.9S63.3%2C56.5%2C61.4%2C56.5z%22/%3E%0A%3C/g%3E%0A%3C/svg%3E%0A");
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            float: left;
            height: 140px;
            width: 140px;
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }

        .header-text {
            padding-left: 1%;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            font-family: "Segoe UI";
            font-size: 72px;
            font-weight: 300;
            letter-spacing: 0.35px;
            line-height: 96px;
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }

        .header-inner-container {
            min-width: 480px;
            max-width: 1366px;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }

            .header-inner-container::after {
                content: "";
                clear: both;
                display: table;
            }

        .main-content-area {
            padding-left: 30px;
        }

        .content-title {
            color: #000000;
            font-family: "Segoe UI";
            font-size: 46px;
            font-weight: 300;
            line-height: 62px;
        }

        .main-text {
            color: #808080;
            font-size: 24px;
            font-family: "Segoe UI";
            font-size: 24px;
            font-weight: 200;
            line-height: 32px;
        }

        .main-text-p1 {
            padding-top: 48px;
            padding-bottom: 28px;
        }

        .endpoint {
            height: 32px;
            width: 571px;
            color: #808080;
            font-family: "Segoe UI";
            font-size: 24px;
            font-weight: 200;
            line-height: 32px;
            padding-top: 28px;
        }

        .how-to-build-section {
            padding-top: 20px;
            padding-left: 30px;
        }

            .how-to-build-section > h3 {
                font-size: 16px;
                font-weight: 600;
                letter-spacing: 0.35px;
                line-height: 22px;
                margin: 0 0 24px 0;
                text-transform: uppercase;
            }

        .step-container {
            display: flex;
            align-items: stretch;
            position: relative;
        }

            .step-container dl {
                border-left: 1px solid #A0A0A0;
                display: block;
                padding: 0 24px;
                margin: 0;
            }

                .step-container dl > dt::before {
                    background-color: white;
                    border: 1px solid #A0A0A0;
                    border-radius: 100%;
                    content: '';
                    left: 47px;
                    height: 11px;
                    position: absolute;
                    width: 11px;
                }

                .step-container dl > .test-bullet::before {
                    background-color: blue;
                }

                .step-container dl > dt {
                    display: block;
                    font-size: inherit;
                    font-weight: bold;
                    line-height: 20px;
                }

                .step-container dl > dd {
                    font-size: inherit;
                    line-height: 20px;
                    margin-left: 0;
                    padding-bottom: 32px;
                }

            .step-container:last-child dl {
                border-left: 1px solid transparent;
            }

        .ctaLink {
            background-color: transparent;
            border: 1px solid transparent;
            color: #006AB1;
            cursor: pointer;
            font-weight: 600;
            padding: 0;
            white-space: normal;
        }

            .ctaLink:focus {
                outline: 1px solid #00bcf2;
            }

            .ctaLink:hover {
                text-decoration: underline;
            }

        .step-icon {
            display: flex;
            height: 38px;
            margin-right: 15px;
            width: 38px;
        }

            .step-icon > div {
                height: 30px;
                width: 30px;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
            }

        .ms-logo-container {
            min-width: 580px;
            max-width: 980px;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            transition: bottom 400ms;
        }

        .ms-logo {
            float: right;
            background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,%0A%3Csvg%20version%3D%221.1%22%20id%3D%22MS-symbol%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A//www.w3.org/2000/svg%22%20xmlns%3Axlink%3D%22http%3A//www.w3.org/1999/xlink%22%20x%3D%220px%22%20y%3D%220px%22%0A%09%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20400%20120%22%20style%3D%22enable-background%3Anew%200%200%20400%20120%3B%22%20xml%3Aspace%3D%22preserve%22%3E%0A%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text/css%22%3E%0A%09.st0%7Bfill%3Anone%3B%7D%0A%09.st1%7Bfill%3A%23737474%3B%7D%0A%09.st2%7Bfill%3A%23D63F26%3B%7D%0A%09.st3%7Bfill%3A%23167D3E%3B%7D%0A%09.st4%7Bfill%3A%232E76BC%3B%7D%0A%09.st5%7Bfill%3A%23FDB813%3B%7D%0A%3C/style%3E%0A%3Crect%20x%3D%220.6%22%20class%3D%22st0%22%20width%3D%22398.7%22%20height%3D%22119%22/%3E%0A%3Cpath%20class%3D%22st1%22%20d%3D%22M171.3%2C38.4v43.2h-7.5V47.7h-0.1l-13.4%2C33.9h-5l-13.7-33.9h-0.1v33.9h-6.9V38.4h10.8l12.4%2C32h0.2l13.1-32H171.3%0A%09z%20M177.6%2C41.7c0-1.2%2C0.4-2.2%2C1.3-3c0.9-0.8%2C1.9-1.2%2C3.1-1.2c1.3%2C0%2C2.4%2C0.4%2C3.2%2C1.3c0.8%2C0.8%2C1.3%2C1.8%2C1.3%2C3c0%2C1.2-0.4%2C2.2-1.3%2C3%0A%09c-0.9%2C0.8-1.9%2C1.2-3.2%2C1.2s-2.3-0.4-3.1-1.2C178%2C43.8%2C177.6%2C42.8%2C177.6%2C41.7z%20M185.7%2C50.6v31h-7.3v-31H185.7z%20M207.8%2C76.3%0A%09c1.1%2C0%2C2.3-0.3%2C3.6-0.8c1.3-0.5%2C2.5-1.2%2C3.6-2v6.8c-1.2%2C0.7-2.5%2C1.2-4%2C1.5c-1.5%2C0.3-3.1%2C0.5-4.9%2C0.5c-4.6%2C0-8.3-1.4-11.1-4.3%0A%09c-2.9-2.9-4.3-6.6-4.3-11c0-5%2C1.5-9.1%2C4.4-12.3c2.9-3.2%2C7-4.8%2C12.4-4.8c1.4%2C0%2C2.7%2C0.2%2C4.1%2C0.5c1.4%2C0.4%2C2.5%2C0.8%2C3.3%2C1.2v7%0A%09c-1.1-0.8-2.3-1.5-3.4-1.9c-1.2-0.5-2.4-0.7-3.6-0.7c-2.9%2C0-5.2%2C0.9-7%2C2.8c-1.8%2C1.9-2.7%2C4.4-2.7%2C7.6c0%2C3.1%2C0.8%2C5.6%2C2.5%2C7.3%0A%09C202.6%2C75.4%2C204.9%2C76.3%2C207.8%2C76.3z%20M235.7%2C50.1c0.6%2C0%2C1.1%2C0%2C1.6%2C0.1s0.9%2C0.2%2C1.2%2C0.3v7.4c-0.4-0.3-0.9-0.5-1.7-0.8%0A%09c-0.7-0.3-1.6-0.4-2.7-0.4c-1.8%2C0-3.3%2C0.8-4.5%2C2.3c-1.2%2C1.5-1.9%2C3.8-1.9%2C7v15.6h-7.3v-31h7.3v4.9h0.1c0.7-1.7%2C1.7-3%2C3-4%0A%09C232.2%2C50.6%2C233.8%2C50.1%2C235.7%2C50.1z%20M238.9%2C66.6c0-5.1%2C1.4-9.2%2C4.3-12.2c2.9-3%2C6.9-4.5%2C12.1-4.5c4.8%2C0%2C8.6%2C1.4%2C11.3%2C4.3%0A%09c2.7%2C2.9%2C4.1%2C6.8%2C4.1%2C11.7c0%2C5-1.4%2C9-4.3%2C12c-2.9%2C3-6.8%2C4.5-11.8%2C4.5c-4.8%2C0-8.6-1.4-11.4-4.2C240.3%2C75.3%2C238.9%2C71.4%2C238.9%2C66.6z%0A%09%20M246.5%2C66.3c0%2C3.2%2C0.7%2C5.7%2C2.2%2C7.4c1.5%2C1.7%2C3.6%2C2.6%2C6.3%2C2.6c2.7%2C0%2C4.7-0.9%2C6.1-2.6c1.4-1.7%2C2.1-4.2%2C2.1-7.6c0-3.3-0.7-5.8-2.2-7.5%0A%09c-1.4-1.7-3.4-2.5-6-2.5c-2.7%2C0-4.7%2C0.9-6.2%2C2.7C247.2%2C60.5%2C246.5%2C63%2C246.5%2C66.3z%20M281.5%2C58.8c0%2C1%2C0.3%2C1.9%2C1%2C2.5%0A%09c0.7%2C0.6%2C2.1%2C1.3%2C4.4%2C2.2c2.9%2C1.2%2C5%2C2.5%2C6.1%2C3.9c1.2%2C1.5%2C1.8%2C3.2%2C1.8%2C5.3c0%2C2.9-1.1%2C5.3-3.4%2C7c-2.2%2C1.8-5.3%2C2.7-9.1%2C2.7%0A%09c-1.3%2C0-2.7-0.2-4.3-0.5c-1.6-0.3-2.9-0.7-4-1.2v-7.2c1.3%2C0.9%2C2.8%2C1.7%2C4.3%2C2.2c1.5%2C0.5%2C2.9%2C0.8%2C4.2%2C0.8c1.6%2C0%2C2.9-0.2%2C3.6-0.7%0A%09c0.8-0.5%2C1.2-1.2%2C1.2-2.3c0-1-0.4-1.9-1.2-2.5c-0.8-0.7-2.4-1.5-4.6-2.4c-2.7-1.1-4.6-2.4-5.7-3.8c-1.1-1.4-1.7-3.2-1.7-5.4%0A%09c0-2.8%2C1.1-5.1%2C3.3-6.9c2.2-1.8%2C5.1-2.7%2C8.6-2.7c1.1%2C0%2C2.3%2C0.1%2C3.6%2C0.4c1.3%2C0.2%2C2.5%2C0.6%2C3.4%2C0.9v6.9c-1-0.6-2.1-1.2-3.4-1.7%0A%09c-1.3-0.5-2.6-0.7-3.8-0.7c-1.4%2C0-2.5%2C0.3-3.2%2C0.8C281.9%2C57.1%2C281.5%2C57.8%2C281.5%2C58.8z%20M297.9%2C66.6c0-5.1%2C1.4-9.2%2C4.3-12.2%0A%09c2.9-3%2C6.9-4.5%2C12.1-4.5c4.8%2C0%2C8.6%2C1.4%2C11.3%2C4.3c2.7%2C2.9%2C4.1%2C6.8%2C4.1%2C11.7c0%2C5-1.4%2C9-4.3%2C12c-2.9%2C3-6.8%2C4.5-11.8%2C4.5%0A%09c-4.8%2C0-8.6-1.4-11.4-4.2C299.4%2C75.3%2C297.9%2C71.4%2C297.9%2C66.6z%20M305.5%2C66.3c0%2C3.2%2C0.7%2C5.7%2C2.2%2C7.4c1.5%2C1.7%2C3.6%2C2.6%2C6.3%2C2.6%0A%09c2.7%2C0%2C4.7-0.9%2C6.1-2.6c1.4-1.7%2C2.1-4.2%2C2.1-7.6c0-3.3-0.7-5.8-2.2-7.5c-1.4-1.7-3.4-2.5-6-2.5c-2.7%2C0-4.7%2C0.9-6.2%2C2.7%0A%09C306.3%2C60.5%2C305.5%2C63%2C305.5%2C66.3z%20M353.9%2C56.6h-10.9v25h-7.4v-25h-5.2v-6h5.2v-4.3c0-3.3%2C1.1-5.9%2C3.2-8c2.1-2.1%2C4.8-3.1%2C8.1-3.1%0A%09c0.9%2C0%2C1.7%2C0%2C2.4%2C0.1c0.7%2C0.1%2C1.3%2C0.2%2C1.8%2C0.4V42c-0.2-0.1-0.7-0.3-1.3-0.5c-0.6-0.2-1.3-0.3-2.1-0.3c-1.5%2C0-2.7%2C0.5-3.5%2C1.4%0A%09s-1.2%2C2.4-1.2%2C4.2v3.7h10.9v-7l7.3-2.2v9.2h7.4v6h-7.4v14.5c0%2C1.9%2C0.3%2C3.3%2C1%2C4c0.7%2C0.8%2C1.8%2C1.2%2C3.3%2C1.2c0.4%2C0%2C0.9-0.1%2C1.5-0.3%0A%09c0.6-0.2%2C1.1-0.4%2C1.6-0.7v6c-0.5%2C0.3-1.2%2C0.5-2.3%2C0.7c-1.1%2C0.2-2.1%2C0.3-3.2%2C0.3c-3.1%2C0-5.4-0.8-6.9-2.5c-1.5-1.6-2.3-4.1-2.3-7.4%0A%09V56.6z%22/%3E%0A%3Cg%3E%0A%09%3Crect%20x%3D%2231%22%20y%3D%2224%22%20class%3D%22st2%22%20width%3D%2234.2%22%20height%3D%2234.2%22/%3E%0A%09%3Crect%20x%3D%2268.8%22%20y%3D%2224%22%20class%3D%22st3%22%20width%3D%2234.2%22%20height%3D%2234.2%22/%3E%0A%09%3Crect%20x%3D%2231%22%20y%3D%2261.8%22%20class%3D%22st4%22%20width%3D%2234.2%22%20height%3D%2234.2%22/%3E%0A%09%3Crect%20x%3D%2268.8%22%20y%3D%2261.8%22%20class%3D%22st5%22%20width%3D%2234.2%22%20height%3D%2234.2%22/%3E%0A%3C/g%3E%0A%3C/svg%3E%0A");
        }

        .ms-logo-container > div {
            min-height: 60px;
            width: 150px;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }

        .row {
            padding: 90px 0px 0 20px;
            min-width: 480px;
            max-width: 1366px;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }

        .column {
            float: left;
            width: 45%;
            padding-right: 20px;
        }

        .row:after {
            content: "";
            display: table;
            clear: both;
        }

        a {
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        .download-the-emulator {
            height: 20px;
            color: #0063B1;
            font-size: 15px;
            line-height: 20px;
            padding-bottom: 70px;
        }

        .how-to-iframe {
            max-width: 700px !important;
            min-width: 650px !important;
            height: 700px !important;
        }

        .remove-frame-height {
            height: 10px;
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width: 1300px) {
            .ms-logo {
                padding-top: 30px;
            }

            .header-text {
                font-size: 40x;
            }

            .column {
                float: none;
                padding-top: 30px;
                width: 100%;
            }

            .ms-logo-container {
                padding-top: 30px;
                min-width: 480px;
                max-width: 650px;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
            }

            .row {
                padding: 20px 0px 0 20px;
                min-width: 480px;
                max-width: 650px;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
            }
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width: 1370px) {
            header {
                background-color: #55A0E0;
                background-size: auto 200px;
            }
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width: 1230px) {
            header {
                background-color: #55A0E0;
                background-size: auto 200px;
            }

            .header-text {
                font-size: 44px;
            }

            .header-icon {
                height: 120px;
                width: 120px;
            }
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
            header {
                background-color: #55A0E0;
                background-image: none;
            }
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width: 632px) {
            .header-text {
                font-size: 32px;
            }

            .row {
                padding: 10px 0px 0 10px;
                max-width: 490px !important;
                min-width: 410px !important;
            }

            .endpoint {
                font-size: 25px;
            }

            .main-text {
                font-size: 20px;
            }

            .step-container dl > dd {
                font-size: 14px;
            }

            .column {
                padding-right: 5px;
            }

            .header-icon {
                height: 110px;
                width: 110px;
            }

            .how-to-iframe {
                max-width: 480px !important;
                min-width: 400px !important;
                height: 650px !important;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
        }

        .remove-frame-height {
            max-height: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <header class="header">
        <div class="header-inner-container">
            <div class="header-icon" style="display: inline-block"></div>
            <div class="header-text" style="display: inline-block">Core Bot Sample</div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column" class="main-content-area">
            <div class="content-title">Your bot is ready!</div>
            <div class="main-text main-text-p1">
                You can test your bot in the Bot Framework Emulator<br />
                by connecting to http://localhost:3978/api/messages.
            </div>
            <div class="main-text download-the-emulator">
                <a class="ctaLink" href="https://aka.ms/bot-framework-F5-download-emulator"
                   target="_blank">Download the Emulator</a>
            </div>
            <div class="main-text">
                Visit <a class="ctaLink" href="https://aka.ms/bot-framework-F5-abs-home" target="_blank">
                    Azure
                    Bot Service
                </a> to register your bot and add it to<br />
                various channels. The bot's endpoint URL typically looks
                like this:
            </div>
            <div class="endpoint">https://<i>your_bots_hostname</i>/api/messages</div>

        </div>
        <div class="column how-to-iframe" id="how-to-iframe">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ms-logo-container">
        <div class="ms-logo"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="botDiv" style="height:38px; position:fixed; bottom:0; z-index:1000; background:#fff">
        <div id="botTitleBar" style="height:38px; width:400px; position:fixed; cursor:pointer; background:blue; color:#fff; font-weight:bold;" onclick="toggleChatbot()">
            ChatBot
        </div>
        <iframe id="botFrame" style="height:600px; width:400px" src="https://webchat.botframework.com/embed/TestBotBasicCSharp?s=[KEY]">
        </iframe>
    </div>

    <!--<script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.js"></script>-->
    <script>
        var toggleChatbot = function () {
            var botDiv = document.querySelector('#botDiv');
            botDiv.style.height = botDiv.style.height == '600px' ? '38px' : '600px';
        };

        //var user = {
        //    id: 'user-id',
        //    name: 'user name'
        //};
        //var botConnection = new BotChat.DirectLine({
        //    token: '[KEY]',
        //    user: user
        //});
        //botConnection
        //    .postActivity({
        //        from: user,
        //        name: 'requestWelcomeDialog',
        //        type: 'event',
        //        value: ''
        //    })
        //    .subscribe(function (id) {
        //        console.log('"trigger requestWelcomeDialog" sent');
        //    });

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>

</script>
```

**DialogBot.cs**

```
    public class DialogBot<T> : ActivityHandler
        where T : Dialog
    {
        protected readonly Dialog Dialog;
        protected readonly BotState ConversationState;
        protected readonly BotState UserState;
        protected readonly ILogger Logger;

        public DialogBot(ConversationState conversationState, UserState userState, T dialog, ILogger<DialogBot<T>> logger)
        {
            ConversationState = conversationState;
            UserState = userState;
            Dialog = dialog;
            Logger = logger;
        }

        public override async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            await base.OnTurnAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);

            // Save any state changes that might have occured during the turn.
            await ConversationState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);
            await UserState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);
        }

        protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            Logger.LogInformation("Running dialog with Message Activity.");

            // Run the Dialog with the new message Activity.
            var welcomeUserStateAccessor = UserState.CreateProperty<WelcomeUserState>(nameof(WelcomeUserState));
            var didBotWelcomeUser = await welcomeUserStateAccessor.GetAsync(turnContext, () => new WelcomeUserState());

            if (didBotWelcomeUser.DidBotWelcomeUser == false)
            {
                didBotWelcomeUser.DidBotWelcomeUser = true;

                // the channel should sends the user name in the 'From' object
                var userName = turnContext.Activity.From.Name;

                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync($"You are seeing this message because this was your first message ever to this bot.", cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync($"It is a good practice to welcome the user and provide personal greeting. For example, welcome {userName}.", cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
            }
            else
            {
                await Dialog.RunAsync(turnContext, ConversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>("DialogState"), cancellationToken);
            }

            // Save any state changes.
            await UserState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext);
        }
    }
```

**DialogAndWelcomeBot.cs**

```
    public class DialogAndWelcomeBot<T> : DialogBot<T>
        where T : Dialog
    {


        public DialogAndWelcomeBot(ConversationState conversationState, UserState userState, T dialog, ILogger<DialogBot<T>> logger)
            : base(conversationState, userState, dialog, logger)
        {
        }

        protected override async Task OnMembersAddedAsync(IList<ChannelAccount> membersAdded, ITurnContext<IConversationUpdateActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            foreach (var member in membersAdded)
            {
                // Greet anyone that was not the target (recipient) of this message.
                // To learn more about Adaptive Cards, see https://aka.ms/msbot-adaptivecards for more details.
                if (member.Id != turnContext.Activity.Recipient.Id)
                {
                    var welcomeCard = CreateAdaptiveCardAttachment();
                    var response = MessageFactory.Attachment(welcomeCard, ssml: "Welcome to Bot Framework!");
                    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(response, cancellationToken);
                    await Dialog.RunAsync(turnContext, ConversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>("DialogState"), cancellationToken);
                }
            }
        }

        // Load attachment from embedded resource.
        private Attachment CreateAdaptiveCardAttachment()
        {
            var cardResourcePath = "CoreBot.Cards.welcomeCard.json";

            using (var stream = GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(cardResourcePath))
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    var adaptiveCard = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    return new Attachment()
                    {
                        ContentType = "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
                        Content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(adaptiveCard),
                    };
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**BotController.cs**

```
    [Route("api/messages")]
    [ApiController]
    public class BotController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter Adapter;
        private readonly IBot Bot;

        public BotController(IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter adapter, IBot bot)
        {
            Adapter = adapter;
            Bot = bot;
        }

        [HttpPost, HttpGet]
        public async Task PostAsync()
        {
            // Delegate the processing of the HTTP POST to the adapter.
            // The adapter will invoke the bot.
            await Adapter.ProcessAsync(Request, Response, Bot);
        }
    }
```

https://testbotbasiccsharp.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: Take a look at the Web Chat [Welcome Message](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/docs/WELCOME_MESSAGE.md) Documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue looks related to the name of the event. The WebChat is sending an event named `requestWelcomeDialog`, where your bot code is looking for an event named `webchat/join`. If you change one of them, it should work.

There are two possibilities for handling welcome messages.

1. Conversation Update. DirectLine broadcasts a conversation update event by default, [however this is not preferred](https://blog.botframework.com/2018/07/12/how-to-properly-send-a-greeting-message-and-common-issues-from-customers/). This event will end up in `OnMembersAddedAsync`.
2. Custom Event. Send a custom event using WebChat v4, as described in [this sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/04.api/a.welcome-event). This event will end up in `OnEventActivityAsync`.

My advice would be to upgrade to the new WebChat (v4) and to have a look at [this sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/04.api/a.welcome-event). The ConversationUpdate has limitations and you are more flexible by sending a custom event.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I already checked that sample and it doesn't work for me. I would use the v4 if I would know how to make it work, but the webchat control seems to not to send any activity message. So I don't know which code I should write in my html or in BotControlller or Bot class...

Comment: Could you update your original post with the full HTML (without keys!) which you are using for the WebChat and add the latest code of your bot. Are you using `DialogAndWelcomeBot.cs` or `DialogBot.cs`.

Comment: ok, I updated the code with the current token key and published the bot so it can be tested.

Comment: To be honest, the start post is a mess now. If you would like to implement the greeting, I would suggest to start with the HTML code in [this example](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/04.api/a.welcome-event). However, your .NET code is also not very clear to me. Are you using `DialogAndWelcomeBot.cs` or `DialogBot.cs`?

Comment: Well, if the code is a mess, it's microsoft's fault, as it is the default template project you get when you run the azure Chatbot with LUIS. I use both, `DialogAndWelcome` and `Dialog` .
I simply added the `botDiv` to the  `default.htm` with the `toggleChatbot` javascript function to open/close, the `WelcomeUserState` and the logic for `OnMessageActitivityAsync` Method for `DialogBot`.

Comment: Do you want to use the iframe or the JS/HTML implementation of the WebChat? With the iframe your options are limited, compared to the JS/HTML implementation. I see you did switch back to the iframe, where in your original post you used the JS/HTML WebChat implementation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208494/discussion-between-mick-and-blfuentes).